# Calculating the grade of students using dictionaries. What can be used instead of eval?

Tags: python

I am a new coder and have seen people on Stack discuss why **eval** use is not recommended. In the following code, we have been given a set of dictionaries with the marks of the students, we take the student name as an input and provide the output as per the formula given (the formula for the calculation of marks).

```
 # 1. Jack's dictionary
Jack = { "name":"Jack",
         "assignment" : [80, 50, 40, 20],
         "test" : [75, 75],
         "lab" : [78.20, 77.20]
       }
        
# 2. James's dictionary
james = { "name":"James",
          "assignment" : [82, 56, 44, 30],
          "test" : [80, 80],
          "lab" : [67.90, 78.72]
        }
 
# 3. Dylan's dictionary
dylan = { "name" : "Dylan",
          "assignment" : [77, 82, 23, 39],
          "test" : [78, 77],
          "lab" : [80, 80]
        }
         
# 4. Jessica's dictionary
jess = { "name" : "Jessica",
         "assignment" : [67, 55, 77, 21],
         "test" : [40, 50],
         "lab" : [69, 44.56]
       }
        
# 5. Tom's dictionary
tom = { "name" : "Tom",
        "assignment" : [29, 89, 60, 56],
        "test" : [65, 56],
        "lab" : [50, 40.6]
      }
name = eval(input())
marks = (0.1*(sum(name['assignment'])/len(name['assignment']))) + (0.7*(sum(name['test'])/len(name['test']))) + (0.2*(sum(name['lab'])/len(name['lab'])))
asci = 65 
print('Average marks of {} is :'.format(name['name']),marks)
def GradeAssign(a,marks,asci):
  if a >= 60: 
   if marks >= a:
      print('Letter Grade of {} is :'.format(name['name']),chr(asci))
   else : 
      a -= 10
      asci += 1
      GradeAssign(a,marks,asci)   
  else :
     print('Letter Grade of {} is :'.format(name['name']),'E')
GradeAssign(90,marks,asci)
```

Now I can't seem to figure out a way to not use eval in the following line:

```
name = eval(input())
```

Comment: Why not make a dictionary where the keys are names and values are score dictionaries? Then you can just use `name = input()`, and use that to access the values in the dictionary.

Comment: I can't change the dictionary as it is provided in the question

Comment: If you can't change the dictionary that is provided to you. Just make a new one out of it.

Comment: If this is homework please add the homework tab. That would clarify the restrictions on the code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I'll do that from the next time, I am fairly new to stack in general so thanks for the help.

Comment: You might want to deserialize the dicts into [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). Handling objects of a fixed structure ist oftentimes easier than handling dicts with possibly arbitrary keys and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Start with a solid foundation**. Even simple scripts like this can benefit by
following a simple rule: put all algorithmic code inside of functions. At the
top level, you can perform imports or define constants, functions, or classes.
Everything else must be in functions. For this program, we could start with the
following sketch:

```
jack = {...}
james = {...}
dylan = {...}
jess = {...}
tom = {...}

def main():
    student = get_student()
    score = compute_score(student)
    letter = compute_grade(score)
    print(score, letter)

def get_student():
    return jack

def compute_score(student):
    return 100

def compute_grade(score):
    return 'A'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Take advantage of data structures**. You have 5 constants in the form of
student dicts. And you have a name that will be entered by the program user
(e.g., 'jack'). You don't need exotic techniques like `eval()` to transform
that user-entered string into a Python variable. Rather, you need a dict
mapping each student name to its corresponding dict of information about the
student. This simple function will do the trick:

```
def collect_students():
    return {
        d['name'].lower() : d
        for d in (jack, james, dylan, jess, tom)
    }
```

**Validate user input**. Once we have that utility function, we can implement
the behavior to get user input and return the corresponding student dict. Code
to collect user input should normally be written with an awareness that people
make mistakes. A `while True` loop is often the most flexible mechanism for
these situations: get the input, validate it, and return if OK:

```
def get_student():
    students = collect_students()
    while True:
        name = input('Enter student name: ')
        try:
            return students[name.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

**Use data structures to simplify algorithms**. Your code to compute the
student's overall score is repetitive (it computes 3 different means) and hard
to read (a long, dense line of code). However, if we define a simple data
structure -- in this case, a dict mapping each type of coursework to its weight
in the overall score -- we can compute the overall score more understandably:

```
def compute_score(student):
    weights = {'assignment': 0.1, 'test': 0.7, 'lab': 0.2}
    return sum(
        w * mean(student[k])
        for k, w in weights.items()
    )

def mean(vals):
    # Better: raise exception if vals is empty.
    # Even better: use statistics.mean().
    return sum(vals) / len(vals)
```

**Use data structures to simplify algorithms -- yet again**. Your code to
compute the letter grade is algorithmically complex (relying on recursion) and
opaque (with cryptic variable names like `asci` and `a`). None of that is
needed if you define a dict mapping each minimum-score to its corresponding
letter grade. (Note that this relies on the insertion-ordering
property of dicts in modern Python.)

```
def compute_grade(score):
    grades = {90: 'A', 80: 'B', 70: 'C', 60: 'D'}
    for min_score, letter in grades.items():
        if score >= min_score:
            return letter
    return 'E'
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer, I am working on making my code more streamlined and this was really helpful.