# Automate the Boring Stuff CH 7: password strength test

Tags: python, regex

This exercise comes from Automate the Boring Stuff Ch 7. The assignment is to use regular expressions to test the strength of a password. Password must be >= 8 characters, contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one number.

Any and all criticisms/suggestions for improving the code are welcome.

````py
# function to test the strength of a password

import re

# pw = password
# function receives user input (password) as argument
def pw_strength_test(pw: str) -> bool:
    is_strong = True # final return value, change to False if test fails
    
    # lowercase, uppercase, and number regexes
    lower_regex = re.compile(r"[a-z]")
    upper_regex = re.compile(r"[A-Z]")
    num_regex = re.compile(r"\d")

    # store matches into lists
    lower_groups = lower_regex.findall(pw)
    upper_groups = upper_regex.findall(pw)
    num_groups = num_regex.findall(pw)

    # def a function to iterate over the regex lists
    # pass list and type into function
    # return number of items of that type
    def count_matches(match_list, match_type):
        count = 0
        try:
            if match_type == str and match_list[0].islower() == True:
                count = len(match_list)
            elif match_type == str and match_list[0].isupper() == True:
                count = len(match_list)
            elif match_type == int:
                count = len(match_list)
        # if no items in list, IndexError will be thrown
        except IndexError:
            print('IndexError thrown. One or more match lists are empty.')

        return count

    # store count into variables
    lower_count = count_matches(lower_groups, str)
    upper_count = count_matches(upper_groups, str)
    num_count = count_matches(num_groups, int)
    
    # if any list contains 0 items, pw test fails
    if lower_count == 0 or upper_count == 0 or num_count == 0:
        is_strong = False
        print("Error: password strength test failed.")
    # if less than 8 characters, pw test fails
    elif (lower_count + upper_count + num_count) < 8:
        is_strong = False
        print("Error: password strength test failed.")
    else:
        print("Password strength test passed.")

    return is_strong

print('Please enter your password.')
pw_strength_test(str(input()))
```
````

Comment: Original link: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter7/

Comment: Obligatory password complexity xkcd: https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The current implementation is too complex**. As soon as you get the results
from the three `findall()` calls, you have essentially everything you need, but
the function continues with over a dozen lines of unnecessary stuff. Remember
that an empty collection evaluates to false in boolean terms, so if the goal is
just to write a function that returns true or false, you could wrap up the
logic as simply as this:

```
return lower_groups and upper_groups and num_groups and len(pw) >= 8
```

**A password checker should not print**. A password testing function should be
a purely data-oriented function: it should take a password and return data; it
should not have other side effects, such as printing. The returned data could be a
`bool` (the simplest implementation) or it could be some other type of object:
for example, a `(bool, error_message)` tuple; or just an `error_message` or
`None` (the code example below takes the latter approach, reframing the
function as a password-error-finder). In any case, you want to keep the
in-depth checking logic in an easily-tested, data-oriented function. Leave the
printing to a different part of the program.

**Collections are often more powerful than separate variables**. If you do want
the function to provide a helpful error message (the current messages are not
helpful, because they do not tell the user specifically what's wrong), you
should consider bundling the checks into a collection so that any failed check
can be linked to its corresponding message. The code
below illustrates one way to do that kind of
thing. It also provides a compact illustration of how **data-centric
thinking can radically simplify code**. The function focuses
nearly all of its attention on building a convenient data
structure. And once we have that data, the rest of the algorithm/logic becomes almost trivial.

```
import re
from typing import Tuple

def check_password(pw: str) -> Tuple[str]:
    checks = {
        'must be at least 8 characters': r'.{8}',
        'must contain lowercase letter': r'[a-z]',
        'must contain uppercase letter': r'[A-Z]',
        'must contain digit': r'\d',
    }
    return tuple(
        err_msg
        for err_msg, pattern in checks.items()
        if not re.search(pattern, pw)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. There's lots to unpack here. Am I to understand that your recommended return statement evaluates to a single Boolean value? `return lower_groups and upper_groups and num_groups and len(pw) >= 8`. So in other words, if any one of those statements resolves to False, then the return Boolean is False. But if all are True, then my final return Boolean is True?

Comment: @Ramza That's correct. Python can do a variety of boolean operations in the [typical ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) using `and`, `or`, and `not`.

Comment: And as for the second part of your response, I understand that the idea is focused on "data-centric thinking," as you called it. I will need more time to read and understand this part of your response, but do you recommend any resources, books, or texts that focus on "data-centric" programming?

Comment: @Ramza I don't have a ready-made reading list that would necessarily be helpful for someone just starting out. However, [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/273036/4612) has some relevant discussion in the comments, including some practical advice that you could follow immediately and some suggestions for a few topics you could research on the internet to get at least a preliminary sense of what data-centric coding means and why it's so useful.

Comment: @Ramza And here's an [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272065/4612) that provides another concrete example: it's a simple problem where we convert algorithmic complexity into simplicity by defining useful data structures. Once you start thinking in these terms, you'll see opportunities for it everywhere – or, as Rob Pike says, "data dominates".

Comment: Thank you for all of the useful information. My mind is still blown by the object you wrote earlier, and I've been thinking about it all morning. It makes perfect sense, though. Why would you store error messages in variables when you can set the strings as keys and the conditionals as values? It would be a nightmare to try tracking down a bunch of variables that are spread out throughout the entirety of the code, along with the conditionals that relate to them.

Comment: For actual use, I would strongly recommend `return [err for (err, ok) in checks.items() if not ok]`. The point being not the use of a "comprehension" (which are good!), but rather that reporting _every_ error detected is a better UX.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter Yes, that's a good improvement for the OP to add.

Comment: The casts to `bool` are redundant as the function output is being used in an `if` statement, which can help shorten this code a bit more.

Comment: Somewhat related side note: initializing the return value with some default may be fine in C, but is incredibly non-pythonic. It also introduces a lot of opportunities for bugs to appear and hide in the flow control not being rigorous enough.

Comment: minor remark on this answer: there's not really any need to make `checks` a dictionary, since you never want to search it by key. You could just make it a list of tuples, which IMO reflects better how it is used.

Comment: @Lodinn Could you clarify, what would a better approach besides initializing a return value with a default value?

Comment: (1) Casting to bool is fine: it plays a minor documentation role and it simplifies type declarations, for those who want to go that route. (2) Initializing a function's return value is also fine: in some circumstances, it's a useful strategy, even though in this case it's not needed/helpful. (3) Making `checks` a dict is fine as well: in the current case, a list of tuples provides no relative benefits and a dict brings no relative costs ... and it is marginally less hassle to define a dict than a list-of-tuples.

Comment: I agree that a dict is not appropriate here. It's not about cost; it's about intent: you're not doing any lookups. A sequence of tuples fits the purpose better. Also: don't `findall`; just `search` - you don't care about "all matches"; you care about "at least one match". Finally: returning presentation strings from a business logic function is not a good idea.

Comment: A more uniform implementation of your strategy would be for the second element of each tuple to be a regular expression only, the first being `.{8,}`. Then your `bool` cast and `search` call would be written once and not four times.

Comment: @Reinderien Not convinced that the dict-vs-tuples question matters in this case. But I agree in principle with your other points, especially the simplifications regarding the regexes, which have the added benefit of reinforcing the regex-learning goal of the exercise. Edited the answer to incorporate your good idea and also to implement the earlier suggestion to return all errors rather than just the first.

Comment: Since none of the regexes contain any characters that need escaping, the `r` can be removed from the string prefix.

Comment: @alexyorke Tastes vary, I suppose, but I always r-quote regexes to minimize thinking about that particular topic. Looks like the other posted answer follows a similar habit, as do many other Python coders.

Answer (score 2):

The original problem description is rather thin. It doesn't require that you print anything, or even indicate why the password was weak. So your `print()` statements can go away. If you did want to add this feature - indicating why a password failed - then you'd either return an `Enum` instance (not a printable string), or raise an exception.

You can condense your regular expressions down to one:

```
import re


PASS_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r'''
    ^            # start of password
    (?=.*?[A-Z]) # lookahead: any characters, then an uppercase letter
    (?=.*?[a-z]) # lookahead: any characters, then a lowercase letter
    (?=.*?[0-9]) # lookahead: any characters, then a digit
    .{8,}        # at least eight characters
    $            # end of password
    ''',
    re.VERBOSE,
)


def is_strong_password(password: str) -> bool:
    return PASS_PATTERN.match(password) is not None
```

Comment: would you mind clarifying the return statement, specifically the part with `is not None`? Perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly, but it seems that `PASS_PATTERN.match(password)` would return `None` instead of a Boolean value if the regex does not find a match.

Comment: You're exactly right - and to convert from a `None` to a `False`, we write `is not None`. The `is` replaces `==` since `None` is a singleton in Python.

Comment: Does that mean that `!= None` has the same effect? This is new to me, because up until now I've been used to very simple return statements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247373/python-none-comparison-should-i-use-is-or

Comment: @Maska Your latest edit first of all would not have worked with `match()`, only with `search()`; and secondly gets into performance topics that I have not bothered to cover. You should post a separate answer with your performance analyses detailed.