# performance - Word ladder leetcode

Tags: python, performance, breadth-first-search

I am working on [Word Ladder - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/)

> Given two words (*beginWord* and *endWord*), and a dictionary's word list, find the length of shortest transformation sequence from *beginWord* to *endWord*, such that:
>
> 1. Only one letter can be changed at a time.
> 2. Each transformed word must exist in the word list. Note that *beginWord* is *not* a transformed word.
>
> **Note:**
>
> - Return 0 if there is no such transformation sequence.
> - All words have the same length.
> - All words contain only lowercase alphabetic characters.
> - You may assume no duplicates in the word list.
> - You may assume *beginWord* and *endWord* are non-empty and are not the same.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> beginWord = "hit",
> endWord = "cog",
> wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]
>
> Output: 5
>
> Explanation: As one shortest transformation is "hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" -> "cog",
> return its length 5.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> beginWord = "hit"
> endWord = "cog"
> wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"]
>
> Output: 0
>
> Explanation: The endWord "cog" is not in wordList, therefore no possible transformation.
> ```

My Approach:

1. Create a graph with word distances
2. Calculate the distance to the endWord using BFS

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def ladderLength(self, beginWord: str, endWord: str, wordList: List[str]) -> int:
        if endWord not in wordList:
            return 0
        
        graph = {}
        wordList = [beginWord] + wordList if beginWord not in wordList else wordList
        for i in range(len(wordList)):
            wordU = wordList[i]
            # Compute distances and prepare a graph when the distance is equal to one
            for j in range(i+1, len(wordList)):
                wordV = wordList[j]

                if wordU not in graph.keys():
                    graph[wordU] = []
                if wordV not in graph.keys():
                    graph[wordV] = []

                if self.word_difference(wordU, wordV) == 1:
                    graph[wordU].append(wordV)
                    graph[wordV].append(wordU)

        visited = set()
        queue = [beginWord]
        distances = {w:1 for w in queue} # since the first word is 1 we are putting 2 here for the root
        return self.BFS(graph, endWord, visited, queue, distances)
    
    def word_difference(self, word1, word2):
        # Compute the difference in words
        distance = 0
        for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
            if c1 != c2:
                distance += 1
        return distance

    def BFS(self, graph, endNode, visited, queue, distances):
        while queue:
            node = queue.pop(0)
            if node not in visited:
                visited.add(node)
            if node == endNode:
                return distances[node]
            for neighbour in graph[node]:
                if neighbour not in visited:
                    visited.add(neighbour)
                    distances[neighbour] = distances[node] + 1
                    queue.append(neighbour)
        return 0
```

The problem is that the above code is failing on a [test case](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/669831752/testcase/) with large word list.

The discussions forum had [a solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/discuss/40723/Simple-to-understand-Python-solution-using-list-preprocessing-and-BFS-beats-95) which took a similar approach but is clearing all the test cases. How can I optimize my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Measure first**. If you have a performance problem, make sure you know where
it is. A simple, low-tech way to do this is to start throwing time markers into
the code and printing the elapsed time for different phases of the work. In
your case, the graph-building is the costly part of the process, so there's no
need to waste time thinking about how to optimize the BFS code.

```
from time import time

t1 = time()
...              # Do some work.
t2 = time()
...              # Do some other work
t3 = time()

print('Phase 1', t2 - t1)
print('Phase 2', t3 - t2)
```

**Your algorithm and the one from the discussion forum are quite different**.
Yes, they both build a graph and then use BFS on it. But, as noted, the
performance problem lies in the graph building. Your algorithm is `O(N*N)`:
nested loops over `wordList`. But the other solution is effectively `O(N)`
because the inner loop is over the positions in the current word, not the
entire word list.

```
# Your approach: O(N*N).
for i in range(len(wordList)):
    ...
    for j in range(i+1, len(wordList)):
        ...

# Discussion forum: O(N*m), where m is tiny, effectively a constant.
for word in word_list:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        ...
```

**Too much computation: word difference is not relevant**. A clue that your
algorithm is inefficient comes from realizing that we don't actually care about
word distances. Our goal is to build a graph linking immediate neighbors (those
having a difference of exactly 1), but your algorithm does the work of actually
computing all pairwise differences.

**Invert the strategy: create linking keys**. Suppose you realize that you
don't need the word differences. The problem becomes, how do we find immediate
neighbors (those having a difference of exactly 1) without actually computing
any differences? That's not an easy question to answer, of course, and to some
extent it requires a leap of insight. Nonetheless, there is still a general
lesson to be learned. The wildcard-based strategy in the discussion forum
achieves that goal by figuring out a way to map each word to some linking-keys,
such that immediate neighbors will share a common key. The way to do that is to
convert each word (a sequence of characters) into other sequences of
characters where each character gets replaced by a generic value.

```
# The word
dog

# Its linking keys
_og
d_g
do_
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your insightful comments. I guess I have to practice more. Is there anything (book/leetcode list/course) that you would suggest?

Comment: @abybaddi009 You're welcome. Yes, practice is crucial. I don't have any ready-made suggestions, other than my regular theme here: **data-centric thinking as a strategy/mindset for reducing/simplifying algorithms**. The linking-key strategy is a data-centric approach to the problem in the sense that it envisions an easily built data structure to achieve the linking without requiring exhaustive pairwise comparisons. You can see a different example of the theme [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/275274/4612) and in a couple of other links I provide in its comments.